# Setting Style for ListBox in MVC Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

This is Razor Syntax for ListBox i am using in my page. How can i set its height and width ?
Here noCategories is View data coming from Controller.

$
@Html.ListBox("noCategories");

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Configure(int? nopCategoryid)
    {
        model = new DataImporttModel();

        DisplaynopCommerceCategories(model, nopCategoryid);

        return View("Nop.Plugin.Data.Import.Views.DataImport.Configure", model);

    }


    private void DisplaynopCommerceCategories(DataImporttModel model, int? nopCategoryid)
    {
        var _categoryservice = new NopEngine().Resolve<ICategoryService>();

        MultiSelectList sl;

        model.nopCommerceCategories = new List<CS_ListItems>();

        foreach (var item in _categoryservice.GetAllCategories().ToList())
        {
            model.nopCommerceCategories.Add(new CS_ListItems() { Name = item.Name, ID = item.Id });
        }

        if (nopCategoryid != null)
        {

            sl = new MultiSelectList(model.nopCommerceCategories, "ID", "Name", new[] { nopCategoryid });
        }
        else
        {
            sl = new MultiSelectList(model.nopCommerceCategories, "ID", "Name");
        }

        ViewData["nopCommerceCategories"] = sl;

    }

public class DataImporttModel
{        
    public List<C_Category> Mappings { get; set; }

    public List<CS_ListItems> ClockCategories { get; set; }

    public List<CS_ListItems> nopCommerceCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply a class to it and then style it through CSS:

```
@Html.ListBox("noCategories", ViewData["nopCommerceCategories"] as MultiSelectList, new {@class = "mylistbox"});
```

**CSS**

```
.myclass{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can style it inline:

```
@Html.ListBox("noCategories", ViewData["nopCommerceCategories"] as MultiSelectList, new {@style = "width: 100px;"});
```